# How do I write "Yoshimeatsu" in Japanese characters?

Tags: translation, word-choice, words

I am doing a study on a Japanese Yakiniku (grilled meat) restaurant named "Yoshimeatsu" and wanted to ask how to write it in Japanese characters? The name was a play on words using Ashikaga Yoshimitsu (a Japanese Shogun) and Meat.

I tried Google Translate and was wondering if this is correct:

> ヨッシー (Yoshi)
> ミート (Meat/Mīto)
> スー (Su)

> ヨッシーミートスー (Yoshimeatsu)

Is it alright to remove the dashes and still convey and sound like Yoshimeatsu?

> ヨッシミトス

Comment: もしかしてこれ？　https://www.cebupot.com/columns/recommended/cebupo202101/#yoshimeatsu `セブ初出店！日本焼肉と韓国焼肉のフュージョン料理 Yoshimeatsu（ヨシミーツ）` / https://www.cega-jp.com/blog/10766 `日本食と韓国料理が融合した食べ放題焼肉店｢YOSHI-MEAT-SU(ヨシミーツ)｣`

Comment: Thank you Chocolate! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The restaurant should be ヨシミーツ in katakana. That shogun is ヨシミツ in katakana, so the only difference is the length of ミ. If you chose other spellings, it would be almost impossible for Japanese speakers to notice the intended pun.

Google translated *yoshi* to ヨッシー because it happens to be the name of [this character](https://www.nintendo.co.jp/kids/character/yoshi/), but ヨッシー is not the standard romaji of *yoshi*. "Tsu" describes one sound, and it must not be divided to トス. You must not remove the long vowel marker between ミ and ト.